# command not found on flutter and i have tried everything

Tags: flutter

I have installed flutter but it is still showing that flutter command not found in mac os intel chip .The path of directory is correct (.zshrc).I have tried changing many things but it still doesnot work.

I have tried reinstalling it and used hommebrew but that is also showing no command found for brew
and the path is correct.

Comment: Have you closed and repopen terminal, and then try again?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the installation path by using this command

echo $PATH

and then check that the flutter/bin directory is added to your PATH

after that run this following command to apply the changes

source ~/.zshrc

Then you can access the flutter doctor command

Comment: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin. this is what coming for echo.